Why $\omega|_S\in\Omega^1(S,\mathfrak{g})$ iff $\omega(\nabla,e)\in\Omega^1(U,\mathfrak{g})$?
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $\mathcal{S}$ be a $G$-strucutre on $M$ and let $\nabla$ be a connection on $TM$.
Let $\omega\in\Omega^1(\text{Fr}(TM),\mathfrak{gl}_r)$ be the connection 1-form associated to the principal connection induced on $\text{Fr}(TM)$ by $\nabla$.
I'm having some troubles proving the following equivalence:

We have that $\omega|_\mathcal{S}\in\Omega^1(\mathcal{S},\mathfrak{g})$ iff for each $\mathcal{S}$-valued local frame $e:U\to \mathcal{S}$, the connection matrix takes values in $\mathfrak{g}$ (the Lie algebra of $G$), i.e.
$$\omega(\nabla,e)\in\Omega^1(U,\mathfrak{g}).$$

This is at page 118 of these lecture notes link. The author says that we have to use the fact that $\omega(\nabla,e)(X_x)=\omega(h_{e_x}(X_x))$, where I presume that $h_{e_x}(X_x)$ is the horizontal lift of $X_x$. But this doesn't seem to make sense, because since $\omega$ is the connection form , it should kill the horizontal vectors: right?

Your question is all about notation. What does $\omega(\nabla,e)$ even mean?

@TedShifrin It's the connection matrix of $\nabla$ with respect to the local frame $e:U\to \mathcal{S}$. Basically, given a vector field $X$ on $U$, we have $$\nabla_X e_j=\sum_i \omega^i_j(X) e_j$$ where $(\omega^i_j){ij}$ are $1$-forms. The matrix of $1$-forms  $(\omega^i_j){ij}$ is called the connection matrix and it's often denoted by $\omega(\nabla,e)$. Basically the condition $\omega(\nabla,e)\in \Omega^1(U,\frak{g})$ means that the real matrix $(\omega^i_j(v))_{ij}$ is an element of $\frak{g}$ for any tangent vector $v\in TU$.

So why is the answer to your question not tautological? What is the definition of $S$?

It looks like a definition, not a statement to prove, where does it come from ?

@TedShifrin $S$ is a $G$-structure, i.e. a $G$ principal sub-bundle of the frame bundle of $M$.

@Cactus This is at page 118 of these lecture notes link. The author says that we have to use the fact that $\omega(\nabla,e)(X_x)=\omega(h_{e_x}(X_x))$, where I presume that $h_{e_x}(X_x)$ is the horizontal lift of $X_x$. But this doesn't seem to make sense, because since $\omega$ is the connection form , it should kill the horizontal vectors: right?

I think what the author probably means is, that $h_{e_x}(X_x)=de(X_x)$ is the horizontal lift of $X_x$ with respect to the $\textbf{trivial}$ connection induced by the frame $e$.

The connection $\omega\in\Omega^1(\text{Fr}(TM),\mathfrak{gl}_r)$ induced by $\nabla$ is characterized by the following property:

For each local frame $e:U\to\mathrm{Fr}(TM)$
$$
e^*\omega=\omega(\nabla,e)
$$

This just means that $\omega(de(X))=\omega(\nabla,e)(X)$ for each $X\in TU$.
Using the definition of $\omega$ given in the linked lecture notes, this can be seen as follows: Let $X=\gamma'(0)\in TU$ be a tangent vector and set $\varepsilon:=e\circ\gamma$. Then
$$
\frac{\nabla\varepsilon_i}{dt}(0)=\nabla_{X}e_i
=\sum_j\omega(\nabla,e)_i^j(X)e_j(\gamma(0))
=\sum_j\omega(\nabla,e)_i^j(X)\varepsilon_j(0)
$$
and therefore $e^*\omega(X)=\omega(\varepsilon'(0))=\omega(\nabla,e)(X)$.
The equivalence can now be obtained as follows:
$\bullet\,$ If $\omega_{|\mathcal{S}}\in\Omega^1(\mathcal{S},\mathfrak{g})$, then for each $\mathcal S$-valued local frame $e:U\to\mathcal S\subset\mathrm{Fr}(TM)$
$$
\omega(\nabla,e)=e^*\omega=e^*(\omega_{|\mathcal S})\in\Omega^1(U,\mathfrak{g})
$$
$\bullet\,$ Conversely, let $Z\in T_u\mathcal S$ be a tangent vector and extend $u$ to a $\mathcal S$-valued local frame $e:U\to\mathcal S$ with $e(x)=u$.
Then $Z$
can be decomposed as $Z=de(X)\oplus\widetilde v_u$ with $X\in T_xM$ and $v\in\mathfrak g$. $(\ast)$
Therefore
$$
\omega_{|\mathcal{S}}(Z)=\omega(Z)=\omega(de(X))+\omega(\tilde v_u)\\
=e^*\omega\,(X)+v
=\omega(\nabla,e)(X)+v
$$
which implies  $\omega|_\mathcal{S}(Z)\in\mathfrak{g}$ provided that $\omega(\nabla,e)\in\Omega^1(U,\mathfrak{g})$.

$(\ast)$ For a local section  $s:U\to \mathcal P$ of a principal $G$-bundle, a tangent vector $Z\in T_{s(x)}\mathcal P$ can be uniquely decomposed as $Z=ds(X)+\widetilde v_{s(x)}$ with $X\in T_xM$ and $v\in\mathfrak g$ where $\widetilde v_{s(x)}=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}s(x)\exp(tv)$, which can be seen by differentiating the principal bundle isomorphism $U\times G\to\mathcal P_{|U}$, $(x,g)\mapsto s(x)g$ at the point $(x,e)$.

Thank you again!
